# Stuck keys but not really stuck

Tags: boot, bios, keys

This is my first post so I apologize in advance for any grammar error, missing information or if there's too much info.

I have an old Dynabook b452/22gm currently with no OS installed.
It wasn't dual boot, only Ubuntu was installed.

This has been going for the last 3 days and since this is a very specific problem, I need help.

At first my laptop suddenly wouldn't boot the OS, going directly to the bios setup. I thought I had a bad hard drive so I took it off the laptop and plugged a new one. Same problem. Then plugged my hard drive running Ubuntu 19.04 in my Desktop PC. Hard drive worked perfectly.

So it's not the hard drive.

Then I thought it could be the bios battery, because the time and date were messed up. Got a new one and didn't solve the problem.

I thought it could be some poor bios configuration so I went searching, did all kinds of trickery with safe mode, unsafe mode, boot order, CSM boot, UEFI boot.

Nothing.

Then I found boot-repair in my searches that at first solved it, but I went to bed and when I woke up with the same problem.

I noticed that when the screen is flickering, I could see the commands the machine were running and between these commands that were most visible on the boot-repair screen were some weird slashes...

"[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^[[[B^"

I didn't suspect many keys could be firing between the commands so I thought it was part of what should've happened but gave it a try and disconnected the keyboard from the motherboard and miraculously it worked perfectly.

The problem is that those keys aren't physically stuck, they only do this during the booting stage, when I manage to boot it, it doesn't EVER happen with the OS running.

What could it be?

Thank you very much if you read it all!